# Counting the number of instanced classes fails in debug mode

Tags: java, virtual-machine, kotlin, allocation, connection-refused

Working on a imgui port in kotlin, I have a `metrics` menu where I display the number of allocations

This is the [init code](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/imgui/Context.kt#L504-L523) I wrote:

```
    try {
        var ac: AttachingConnector? = null
        for (x in Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager().attachingConnectors()) {
            if (x.javaClass.name.toLowerCase().indexOf("socket") != -1) {
                ac = x
                break
            }
        }
        if (ac == null) {
            throw Error("No socket attaching connector found")
        }
        val connectArgs = HashMap<String, Argument>(ac.defaultArguments())
        connectArgs["hostname"]!!.setValue("127.0.0.1")
        connectArgs["port"]!!.setValue(Integer.toString(3001))
        connectArgs["timeout"]!!.setValue("3000")
        vm = ac.attach(connectArgs)
    } catch (error: Exception) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't retrieve the number of allocations, $error")
    }
```

And these are the arguments I pass in as 'VM options'

`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=3001,server=y,suspend=n`

Whenever I run it normally, it works. But if I run it in debug mode, it doesnt, returning the following error:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

I couldn't find yet a solution for that, at the moment I simply display a `-1` to indicate an error

Does anyone have a solution/explanation about?

Specs:

- Kotlin 1.2-m1
- Idea 2017.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you try to use the same port for the debugger as the one used by the program. Try to use a different port for the debugger.